# How to draw or copy a image as realistic texture for 3d models?

Tags: modeling, texturing, texture-painting

How to draw or copy a image as texture for 3d models?

I've tried to copy some images from Internet but they can't fill my model smoothly since they aren't seamless texture.

So I want to draw my own texture, and I want to know if there are some methods or tools that can draw realistic texture easily.

I've had problems with car tire there is repeat pattern problem.
This texture is from the game model file.
[image]
,and this one is from my own model.
[image]
How to make texture more realistic like the first image?

Comment: Texturing, especially texture painting is an art form, there is no short answer here. You should check out how to do it in general and for realism using the clone function to copy parts from actual photos is probably the way to go for you.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Edit your previous question instead.

Comment: Your question gets no answer because it is too broad and subjective. Try to explain what you've done so far and how and tell what specific issue you've encountered. Thanks.

Comment: You can block out the base colors of the texture with texture baking. Add an Ambient Occlusion node to the material & you will get a base to work with. The dirt, scratches, etc you have to paint. This can but done on an extra texture & mixed into the base texture and finally, bake it again. The pattern for the tires can be done with normals (https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-add-tyre-tread-using-normal-map/1114861/4), uv map it and then bake it as normals to your texture.